# How to authenticate the client using SslStream class

Tags: sockets, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, sslstream

I got the problem with my code
I'm trying to create sslStream between client and server but I'm getting the next error:

*Request error: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was received.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.GetFrameSize(ReadOnlySpan'1 buffer)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder'1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Node.ProxyServer.OnAcceptSocketAsync() in /Users/main/Desktop/Node/Node/ProxyServer.cs:line 162*

So this error is caused by *await sslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync* line and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

```
private async Task OnAcceptSocketAsync()
        {
            while (ListeningSocket != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var accept = await ListeningSocket.AcceptAsync();
                    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(accept), false);
                    await sslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(ServerCertificate, clientCertificateRequired: false, SslProtocols.Default, checkCertificateRevocation: true);
                    TunnelStructure tunnel = new TunnelStructure()
                    {
                        key = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        client = accept,
                        sslClientStream = sslStream,
                    };
                    await ConnectAsync(tunnel);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                   
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried to validate server and client certificate, specified different SslProtocols but no changes.